# How can I put an icon and an input text on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I want to put an icon on the left and an input type text on the right occupying all the remaining space.

```
----------------------------------------------------
| [ico]  ----------------------------------------  |
|        |   input type="text"                  |  |
|        ----------------------------------------  |
----------------------------------------------------
```

If I set both with `display: inline-block` and set the **input's width to `100%`** it **jumps the line**, because `100%` is **not considering the `space - icosize`**...

I want to **expand the input to the remaining available space** (**I don't care for vertical align**). Is there a way to achieve this behavior without using tables?

> **[An example of the problem on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sUYBS/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit less complicated that ianaré's version and works in IE6:

http://jsfiddle.net/sUYBS/23/

Answer (score 2):

Try this ...

```
<div style="display: table;">
<div style="display: table-row; width:100%;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
    <img src="img.png" width="16" height="11" alt="img"/>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width:100%;">
    <input type="text" style="width:100%;"/>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work on IE7. But it does work on IE8+ and on browsers. That is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: If you use a display: table, a display: table-row and a display: table-cell, why in the hell not a <table> ? Is it a sin after 2000 to use tables?

Comment: @Augusto: haha, I though it would be possible to make it without tables. But it seems it is not possible. I'm going to use tables. I was just curious if there were a simpler way to achieve it.

Comment: @Augusto - display:table etc., does not have the same accessibility issues as using `<table>`. I.e., a screen reader won't read out "Table of one row and two columns" before the contents. Not a big issue for one layout table, but lots of them would be at best annoying, and at worst would make the page incomprehensible.

Comment: @Alohci But you know if quack like a table, it´s probably a table, looks like duck typing in CSS!

Comment: @Augusto - Right. But my point is that while it looks like a duck, it doesn't quack at all.

Answer (score 1):

`float:left;` for the icon.
See, http://jsfiddle.net/sUYBS/11/

Comment: Why the down vote? The float actually solves your problem, don't it?

Comment: +1 for simplicity.  Plus this is a lot more compatible than the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes. Honestly, I do agree its not the most satisfying result but I always tend to stick to the simpler way, lesser markup, lesser code.

Comment: *Most* satisfying result? You got it wrong. The input is not occupying all the available space. You removed the `width: 100%`. It does keep both elements on the same line (which I am already doing by setting `display: block`) but it doesn't make the input to occupy the remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

i think the answer is `vertical-align: middle` but see [Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)

Comment: The problem AFAICT is not vertical centering; it's getting the two elements to sit side-by-side horizontally while having the second element expand to fill available space.

Comment: mmm, if what you want is for the ico to be on the same line as the input but for the input to fill the rest of the space i.e. be as width as it can

Comment: What the vertical alignment has to do with the input occupying free space?

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: table-cell` .

Comment: You put it in the same place you had the `display: inline-block`. You're on your own for testing various browsers, but it's definitely standard CSS.

Comment: Hmm, I played around with it on jsFiddle and it doesn't seem to work like I expected it to. :(

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to use align="absmiddle" in the icon?

```
<img src="img.jpg" align="absmiddle">
```

Comment: What the vertical alignment of the icon has to do with the input occupying free space?