# CSS: expression ( use percentage & pixels to calculate )

Tags: css, expression

i want to set the width of the DIV like

```
( 100% - 10px )
```

using CSS expression but have been failing can somebody tell me what is the answer to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that unfortunatly, and it can be annoying because you do run into instances where it would be great.

You can use Javascript to work out pixel widths of elements, but this gets messy and very complicated to manage very quickly.

My recommendation is go back to the drawing board and redesign your layout to work around this issue.

If you post specific examples we might be able to help.

Comment: i am not looking for specific solutions... i actually love non-centralized, full spanning website designs and in that if somehow i might be able to do it, its gonna be a great help...

Comment: <div style="width:100%;padding-right:10px;"><div style="width:100%;"></div><div>

Comment: dig this... a DIV with 100% width.... with two divs inside it.. one floating left & one right... both with same exactly same with width and 10px distance in between them... & if you manage to set it up for one resolution... try other resolutions & try resizing  the window... & remember the distance between them must not exceed 10px...

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly this today with [CSS3's calc function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

```
width: calc(100% - 10px);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use javascript to get the actual width of the div when you have it at 100% and then reduce it by 10(might i recommend jquery as a greate framework to work with when it comes to javascript), another thing would create a wrapping div with overflow:hidden; and that's 100% and then you apply 100% to the inside div too and add left:-10px; to it, it will create desired effect

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a more concrete example? Just without any more details it seems you just need a left or right margin of 10px on an block element with default (`auto`) width.

Comment: well its a little hard to explain my particular scenario... actually i am working non-centralized website design so i need to set width on ( percentages - pixels ) & all... but could it be done

Comment: Sorry, missed your comment until now. What do you mean with "non-centralized"? While it isn't possible to actually calculate in CSS, there are several was to "simulate" it, if you give a concrete scenario. Take this recent question and my answer to it as an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313643/how-can-i-put-an-icon-and-an-input-text-on-the-same-line/4314557#4314557