# calc(pecentage) to calc(pixel)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to use `calc(100%-100px)` which didn't work in my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/az4dB/1/) as the height is only accepting in pixels so how to convert this percentage value to pixels.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: expression ( use percentage & pixels to calculate )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345047/css-expression-use-percentage-pixels-to-calculate)

Comment: FYI put whitespaces before and after the -. Some browsers don't like it if you put it right behind the % and right before the second value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give you height:

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

To set the values

```
$(window).height(800);
$(document).height(800);
```

Or you could use good old Javascript

```
window.resizeTo(800, 600);
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/az4dB/5/) you asked for in comments.

Comment: Use `$('#divId').height(100).width(200);`.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

div {
    height: calc(100% - 100px); /* IE9+ and future browsers */
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px); /* Firefox */
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px); /* Chrome, Safari */
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: yellow;
}

p{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Seems like table-cell doesn't allow calc(...)

See: http://jsfiddle.net/az4dB/3/

**EDIT:**

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/az4dB/6) example, adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/84616/982026) awesome post:.

Comment: vertical-align is not working ,, i mean height is not working.

Comment: Why not? How is the fiddle looking in your browser? Which browser do you use?